# How can I cleanly combine a number of prefixes of the same string?

Tags: python, defaultdict

For example, if my string is

```
lst= [44,44 , 44]
```

and my prefix lengths are

```
lens = [2, 2, 2]


   for k,v in zip(key,value):
         #dic[k] = v
         dic[k].append(v)
```

I made this with defaultdict

```
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(),reverse=True))
od-> OrderedDict([('44', [2,2,2])])
```

I want to iterate through the `[2,2,2]` and make a string equivalent to

```
'44'[:2] + '44'[:2] + '44'[:2]
```

and end up with a single string like `'444444'`.

Comment: Can you simplify your problem?  It doesn't actually have anything to do with `defaultdict` as written.  It is unclear if it even has anything to do with `OrderedDict`.  I proposed an edit that simplifies your problem to your actual question

Comment: I'm not even sure this has anything to do with `dict`s. As described, you only have one key with one `list` of values. What happens when the `dict` has more than one key? Is the result one string total, or one string per key?

Comment: I made ([('4444', [1, 1, 1, 1, 2])]) orderDict. and now I want to iter through the 1,1,1,1,2 to cut the string of '4444' for each iteration. like 4444[:1] + 4444[:1].....+4444[:2]

Comment: but without defaultdict I can not make the form with od-> OrderedDict([('4444', [1, 1, 1, 1, 2])])

Comment: Does my edit make sense?  Perhaps looking at it from that perspective answers your question

Comment: @Cireo: With or without `OrderedDict`, a `dict` with a single key will have a single iteration order; there's only one key, so there's no other option. Also note that as of CPython/PyPy 3.6 (and any interpreter 3.7), plain `dict`s are insertion ordered, so `OrderedDict` is mostly for the case where you need to be able to reorder the keys with `move_to_end` or the like.

Comment: I change the question. I skip though the sort process. so this might confuse the people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your original example (which seems a bit over-complicated):

```
import collections

x = collections.OrderedDict([('4444', [1, 1, 1, 1, 2])])
print(''.join([k[:v] for k, vs in x.items() for v in vs]))
```

Explanation:

- `''.join(<some list here>)` takes a list and joins its elements into a string separated by the given string.
- `[k[:v] for k, vs in x.items() for v in vs]` is a list comprehension, taking every key `k` and values `vs` (which is a list in your case) from the items of a dictionary, and then taking every value `v` from that list and adding `k[:v]` for each combination to the list in order.

In general, if you have a list and a string and you'd like to create a concatenation of prefixes of that string based on the lengths in the list:

```
s = '12345'
ls = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
result = ''.join([s[:l] for l in ls])
```

Not sure what good it would be though...